# Pure socket logic

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a nodejs app, and every client has an open socket connection, the reason i am using sockets  because I need to update the data on the client whenever the data in the database changes by an external process.

However every other operation in my app doesn't require a socket connection and mostly initiated by the client (CRUD operations), But i am confused about one thing since I always have an open socket connection, wouldn't it be better to use that socket connection for every operation and make the app with pure `socket` logic?

Comment: This sounds more like a theory question than a programming question.

Comment: @SLoW i don't think so, its a clear question simply if you have an open socket connection all the time, should you use it for all request that are initiated by the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `websockets` maybe it's fine. But if `socket.io` [switches to XHR (AJAX) transport](http://socket.io/#browser-support) it might be irrational.

Take a look at the differencies of these two approaches:

- In case of simple AJAX (without `socket.io`) when you want to get some info from server, or change something on a server, you send GET or POST request,
  and server responses. Everything's fine.
- But in case of `socket.io` (XHR transport) there is one request to send data, and another to get the response.
  (You can make your own experiment - write [`io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);`](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO) and try to send data to the server and make server respond -
  you will see 2 AJAX requests in the Network tab)

So instead of one AJAX request `socket.io` makes two requests.
This is not because socket.io is bad. This is a feature of sockets approach. This approach is good if you want one side (client or server) to send messages independenly from the other. This is what `socket.io` does very good.
But if you want to do "request-response" stuff it's the best to use simple AJAX because of traffic economy (note that I compare simple AJAX to `socket.io` AJAX. Websockets - is another story).

But since this question is about approaches and can't have 100% "yes" or "no" answer, there are might be different opinions.

Sorry for English. I tried to write as clearly as I could :)

Comment: so i better take a hybrid approach and only use the open socket connection for the requests that are initiated by the server (for example updating some data on the client after it changes by an external process in the database), and use GET/POST requests for the usual CRUD operations?

Comment: @user3318998 in case you've just described (requests initiated by server) you don't have to receive some data back from client, right? If so, socket.io would be ideal. socket.io is fine anyway, but in some cases plain AJAX would be better because of traffic economy.

Comment: @user3318998 you're welcome :) It's also worth to note that you don't have to take my answer as 100% truth. This is just my own opinion. Try  to perform different approaches unless you find optimal decision for youself